# How to change paging links width

Tags: datatables

I translated DataTables links to brazilian portuguese and now I'm having a problem with links' width as some of the used words are longer than the original english word. How can I resize these links?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you translate it ?
I tried to translate it and it works well.
The text is inside a `span` which class is `paginate_button` so no problem with the content width, btw you can style it using css.

Just an example:

```
.dataTables_paginate span.first,
.dataTables_paginate span.last {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: I replaced the original values on datatables js file. I'll try to change the width the way you suggested.

Comment: @JulianoNunesSilvaOliveira Hope it help you.